# Obnoxiously noisy dialogue

Tags: dialogue, noise-reduction

I just got some pretty terribly recorded dialogue with a lot of hiss on the track and have been trying to get rid of it with C4 and RX denoiser but I can't seem to completely get rid of the hiss. Not to mention it's incredibly distant and this is the only take...Any suggestions?

http://snd.sc/MacqC0

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to work some magic with those tools with a bit of patience. Apart from getting your hands on a CEDAR or ADR-ing it, you might get something half decent to work with.

Heres what I did in 3 mins using RX: http://soundcloud.com/andrewjohnlewis/noisy-dialogue-2

Very rough, but with some finesse you could get somewhere there I'm sure.

Comment: @Andy Did you just use the Denoiser?

Comment: Yup. On the D setting and tweaking the curve settings on the advanced tab bit. 2 passes with about 5db reduction each time

Comment: Thanks Andy. After a while it seemed to do the job. I had never fooled around with the advanced tab before. 

Comment: As you can tell I don't work often enough in dialogue editing. 